# Return a variable outside a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a variable id inside a function

How can I return the variabe id outside of the function

```
public async info(version,login,password) {
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "**",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: "*"
       },
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, issue) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log("Response: " + response.statusCode + " " + response.statusMessage);

        const json = JSON.parse(issue);
        for (let i = 0; i < json.versions.length; i++) {
            const test = json.versions[i].name;
            if (test === version) {
                const id = json.versions[i].id; // want to return this value 
            }
        }
    });
    return this.doTest(id, login, password); // didn't know what is id here
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call